# Android RecycleView EditText updating wrong rows

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I am implementing a shopping cart in my App. Products are displayed using `RecyclerView`, it has a `EditText` for user entering Quantity.
Looks like this:

**Screen shot**

[image: Screenshot]

**Problem:**
Right now i have 13 products. Suppose i enter quantity as 1.0, 2.5, 3.5 as for products 2, 3 and 4, and then i scroll down to the end and come back to the beginning of the screen, quantity is set as 1.0, 2.5, 3.5, 1.0, 2.5 and 3.5 for products 2,3,4,11,12,13 respectively.

I have searched a lot for similar issues on SO, but so far nothing helped. Please help.

**My code is:**

```
package com.organicbasket.retailer_app.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.organicbasket.retailer_app.R;
import com.organicbasket.retailer_app.fragment.ProductListFragment;
import com.organicbasket.retailer_app.model.Product;
import com.organicbasket.retailer_app.society.ShoppingActivity;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty;

public class ProductListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductListAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {
    private ShoppingActivity shoppingActivity;
    private final Context context;
    private ProductListFragment productListFragment;
    private ArrayList<Product> productItems;

    public ProductListAdapter(ShoppingActivity activity, List<Product> productItems, ProductListFragment productListFragment) {
        this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
        this.shoppingActivity = activity;
        this.productListFragment = productListFragment;
        this.productItems = new ArrayList<>();
        this.productItems.addAll(productItems);
    }

    public class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView thumbNail;
        TextView name;
        TextView rate;
        EditText etQuantity;
        TextView remarks;
        Button addToCart;

        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            rate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rate);
            etQuantity = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            remarks = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.remarks);
            thumbNail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            addToCart = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addtocart);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.productlist_row, viewGroup, false);
        ProductViewHolder viewHolder = new ProductViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        Product currentProduct;
        currentProduct = productItems.get(position);

        viewHolder.etQuantity.setText(Double.toString(productItems.get(position).getItemQuantity()));

        viewHolder.name.setText(currentProduct.getName());
        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##.###");
        viewHolder.rate.setText("Rs " + String.valueOf(currentProduct.getRate()) + " per " + nf.format(currentProduct.getQuantity()) + " " + String.valueOf(currentProduct.getUnit()));
        viewHolder.remarks.setText(String.valueOf(currentProduct.getRemarks()));

        viewHolder.etQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                 @Override
                 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

                 @Override
                 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

                 @Override
                 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                     double value = 0.0;

                     if(shoppingActivity.productList.size() <= 0){
                         return;
                     }

                     if (isEmpty(s.toString())){
                         for (int i = 0; i < shoppingActivity.myCart.productList.size(); i++) {
                             if (Integer.toString(productItems.get(position).getID()).equals(Integer.toString(shoppingActivity.myCart.productList.get(i).getID()))) {
                                 shoppingActivity.myCart.productList.remove(i);
                                 break;
                             }
                         }
                         for (int i = 0; i < shoppingActivity.productList.size(); i++) {
                             if (Integer.toString(productItems.get(position).getID()).equals(Integer.toString(shoppingActivity.productList.get(i).getID()))) {
                                 shoppingActivity.productList.get(i).setItemQuantity(0);
                                 break;
                             }
                         }

                         viewHolder.addToCart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                         Toast.makeText(shoppingActivity, "Removed from Cart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         return;
                     }

                     try {
                         value = Double.parseDouble(s.toString());
                         if(value <= 0) {
                             viewHolder.addToCart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                             return;
                         }

                         if (viewHolder.addToCart.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                             for (int i = 0; i < shoppingActivity.productList.size(); i++) {
                                 if (Integer.toString(productItems.get(position).getID()).equals(Integer.toString(shoppingActivity.productList.get(i).getID()))) {
                                     shoppingActivity.productList.get(i).setItemQuantity(value);
                                     break;
                                 }
                             }

                             for (int i = 0; i < shoppingActivity.myCart.productList.size(); i++) {
                                 if (Integer.toString(productItems.get(position).getID()).equals(Integer.toString(shoppingActivity.myCart.productList.get(i).getID()))) {
                                     shoppingActivity.myCart.productList.get(i).setItemQuantity(value);
                                     break;
                                 }
                             }

                         } else {
                             shoppingActivity.myCart.productList.add(productItems.get(position));
                             for (int i = 0; i < shoppingActivity.productList.size(); i++) {
                                 if (Integer.toString(productItems.get(position).getID()).equals(Integer.toString(shoppingActivity.productList.get(i).getID()))) {
                                     shoppingActivity.productList.get(i).setItemQuantity(value);
                                     break;
                                 }
                             }
                             viewHolder.addToCart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                             viewHolder.addToCart.setText("REMOVE");
                             viewHolder.addToCart.setBackground(shoppingActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_button_purple));
                             viewHolder.addToCart.setTextColor(shoppingActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

                         }
                     }
                     catch (Exception e){

                     }

                 }
             }
        );

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

}
```

Comment: check position.

Comment: Try to use an extra variable to store the quantity, and in afterTextChanged(), update the quantity variable. in onBindViewHolder(), before checking anything, check the quantity variable, if you have any values, then directly set the quantity variable value to your edittext.

Comment: Its not a good practice to use Edittext inside recycler views item. Instead of it you can use a textView with Plus and Minus icon on both side  . Or if your input is not in integer the you can use a dialog to get floating input from user .

Comment: Agreed which Mohd Asif Ahmed, onBindViewHolder is being called when the view hide sand reappear again on the screen. Put a code where you set the value to the edit text from the variable you hold the quantity you set on afterTextChanged()

Comment: I am doing that, i am storing the quantity against product and setting it to EditText                                                                                                               viewHolder.etQuantity.setText(Double.toString(productItems.get(position).getItemQuantity()));

Comment: When i scroll back from bottom of screen to top, onBindViewHolder is called  with position 3 with a wrong viewHolder of product 12

Comment: @Padmashree try my answer i think it solve your problem for current situation.

Comment: call "removeTextChangedListener" before "viewHolder.etQuantity.setText". Maybe your listener is erroneously called in onBindViewHolder.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:-

Just add `viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);` in `onBindViewHolder`

Comment: I don't think that this idea is good for this current situation, as it violates the purpose of RecyclerView.

Comment: @TentenPonce i know but thats a patch..in a simple and easy way.and it suit for current situation also man..

Comment: you just save me...it's not ideal but it works, let future me find better solution

Answer (score -1):

Just add following lines of code in the adapter class to achieve the results,

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```